# Inferring generics when using extends

Tags: typescript

Today, I came across this type:

```
interface Base {
  one: number;
  two: number;
}

export type SelectSubset<T, U> = {
    [key in keyof T]: key extends keyof U ? T[key] : never
}

type TQuestion = <T extends Base>(args: SelectSubset<T, Base>) => void

const example: TQuestion = (obj) => {}
```

I'm extremely unsure why the type of the generic `T` can be inferred in this example. I see that `T` is constrained to Base but would assume that I'd have to pass a default value for the compiler to figure out what T resolves to. I'm assuming that the compiler simply assumes `T` has the type of `Base` of no explicit type is passed?

Comment: the compiler hasn't figured out anything in there, it doesn't need to. The `T` constraint needs to be checked when you *call* the `example` function and pass in an argument. The argument's type will be checked against the constraint only then.

Comment: a function of type `<T extends Base>(args: SelectSubset<T, Base>) => void` merely means that **when it is called** and passed the `args` argument, said argument must be of type `SelectSubset<T, Base>`, where `T` is constrained to `Base`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet you've posted, there's no real inferring needed to be done by the compiler.

In this line-

```
const example: TQuestion = (obj) => {};
```

you've merely defined a function of type `TQuestion`, no inferring needs to be done here. Since no type is explicitly mentioned on the `obj` parameter, it's picked up from the `TQuestion` type. This is equivalent to-

```
function example<T extends Base>(obj: SelectSubset<T, Base>): void {}
```

If you did-

```
const example = (obj) => {};
```

The compiler would complain about `obj` is missing a type and has an implicit `any` type (assuming you have the "no implicit any" setting set to true). Here, a type is completely missing, but when you declare `example` to be of type `TQuestion`, the function you store in it **should be** of type `TQuestion`, which is why the `obj` parameter automatically gets the type `SelectSubset<T, Base>`

The actual inferring and type checking of these constraints only come into play once you actually call the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have to let that sink in a minute. It hasn't yet clicked 100%.  I'm still having trouble understanding what type T ultimately has (even if it's just a contained type). For example: I don't understand why this doesn't work: `type Question = <T extends Base>(args: SelectSubset<T, Base>) => {[key in keyof T]: T[key]};`and `const example: Question = (obj) => ({one: 1, two: 2})`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=54#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnID2IEAXMiAK4C2ARtANz7JgDuh5VdjuAvrrggAPAA6EoYFgE8RKAMoQANhARg5lWljAAeACoAaZAFUAfMgC8yPAQIBtANYQpyUMkdTCMZLoC65d8jCkCAAJhhuTp7GyAD83g5OPsicEABu0HwCYDIoAIqUEBhgwMQWyHqBQsFhaJgQJgAUcFAA5hjkCsqq6poQOga1WCYAlBZm2AnOru5RvuS6kz68TLgIxEWVcNQiyuT5hcWllg2EtABWo+ZmDdjEZMgAjIZsHMgATLzDuEA

Comment: @Xen_mar There is no "ultimate" type `T` has gotten in the function declaration. It is merely a declaration. The "ultimate" type will only be figured out when you call the function and pass an argument, at which point, `T` will become the type of the argument you passed to it (after performing `SelectSubset`).

Comment: @Xen_mar The reason your example does not work is simply because inside the function definition, `T` is related to `obj` (i.e, the argument) - so the return value must be made relative to the argument in order for it to be constrained.

Comment: It should probably be noted, that `SelectSubset<T, Base>` will always be equivalent to `Base`, so you probably don't need generics in this specific example at all. You can pass a type that has more properties than the `Base` properties just fine anyway.

Comment: Hey @Chase, thanks again for your detailed answers! Is there any documentation that could help me understand, why my example does not work? I am completely unaware of what it means that `T` is "related" to `obj` and how to make the return value "relative". I've noticed that I can return `obj` without any error - but the why still is a mystery to me.

Comment: @Xen_mar I'd suggest the [official doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) if you haven't already read it. The reason you can't return a concrete type in the function, is simply because you cannot guarantee that the generic type *will be exactly* the same as the concrete type you're returning. Remember, "generics" are specifically to *generalize* types. You can't return the type `{ one: number; two: number }` because you don't know if that's exactly what `T` **will be**. `T` could have more keys! Which will be determined based on the argument you pass!